# Add and later access Leaflet.draw polyline index and a new property value

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am using the Leaflet draw plugin located at

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

and what I want to do is when a person draws a new polyline to print in the console the index number of that polyline and also add a value such as color:'red' to its properties.

Then when I click that line to edit it later also print to the console the index number and the value stored in the color property.

Comment: I was able to implement what is here, but what happens if you edit two items and then press save or cancel? I would want to save the coords back to a database for each modified line. My process was when the line was initially created and placed into the DB, I grabbed its DB id and added it to the properties so can later retrieve it.

Also what is the difference in listening for the edit using e.layer.on('edit', logProps); and having a 

map.on('draw:edited', function(e) {
...
});

Answer (score 2):

You can access Leaflet's internal layer id using `L.stamp` and set the color of the polyline by changing its `.options.color` property. To log the properties to the console each time the layer is edited, you will want to listen for the `edit` event:

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  console.log('Layer created: ' + L.stamp(e.layer));
  e.layer.options.color='red';
  e.layer.on('edit', logProps);
  featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
});

function logProps(e) {
  console.log('Layer edited: ' + L.stamp(e.target));
  console.log('Color: ' + e.target.options.previousOptions.color);
}
```

Styles are changed during editing, so to access the line's color, you will need to use `.options.previousOptions.color`, which contains the color as originally assigned.

Example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/nh8hg7zq/

Comment: I was able to implement what is here, but what happens if you edit two items and then press save or cancel? I would want to save the coords back to a database for each modified line. My process was when the line was initially created and placed into the DB, I grabbed its DB id and added it to the properties so can later retrieve it.

Also what is the difference in listening for the edit using e.layer.on('edit', logProps); and having a 

map.on('draw:edited', function(e) {
...
});

Comment: In this example, saving or pressing cancel has no effect on whether the ids and colors are logged to the console. The `edit` event is tied to an individual layer (polyline, marker, etc.) and fires each time that layer is edited. For a polyline, this would include adding and moving vertices. The `draw:edited` event only fires when the edit operation is completed (saved), and it includes the entire `layerGroup` (which may consist of multiple layers).

Comment: I have also discovered that this does not work with the newer leaflet draw plugin as posted on GitHub - or at least the previousOptions part does not work. It might be that this just works with v0.2.2 as hosted by mapBox.

Comment: I confirmed that just upgrading the leaflet draw js from 0.2.2 to the file at the following breaks the access to the color property.  https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-draw/v0.2.3/leaflet.draw.js